# while loop and dictionary issue

Tags: python, list, dictionary, while-loop

I am attempting to create a text based game using Python.

My current problem involves me trying to build the combat system. At the beginning it will display you and the enemy stats (SKILL/STAMINA) and then your options (ATTACK/ITEM/FLEE).

When you select ATTACK, a successful hit should remove 2 stamina from whichever is hit.

My issue  is the overall stamina doesn't seem to want to decrease:

```
tempSkill = skill
tempStamina = stamina
tempLuck = luck

enemyName = Creature.goblin['enemy_name']
enemySkillTemp = Creature.goblin['skill']
enemyStamina = Creature.goblin['stamina']

while enemyStamina and tempStamina > 0:
        print(f"\nyou encountered {enemyName}!")
        print(f"{enemyName} | SKILL: {enemySkillTemp} | STAMINA: {enemyStamina}")
        print(f"{name.upper()} | SKILL: {tempSkill} | STAMINA: {tempStamina}")

        print("1. ATTACK")
        print("2. ITEM")
        print("3. FLEE")

        choice = input("\nMake your choice: (1, 2, 3): ")
        choice = int(choice)
        if choice == 1:
            playerAS = Combat.attackSkillRoll(tempSkill)
            enemyAS = Combat.attackSkillRoll(enemySkillTemp)
            print("\nATTACK!")
            print(f"{enemyName} rolled {enemyAS - enemySkillTemp}! | Attack Strength: {enemyAS}")
            print(f"{name.upper()} rolled {playerAS - tempSkill}! | Attack Strength: {playerAS}")
            if enemyAS > playerAS:
                 print(f"{name.upper} wounded! (-2 STAMINA)")
                 print(Combat.wound(tempStamina))
            elif playerAS > enemyAS:
                 print(f"{enemyName} wounded! (-2 STAMINA)")
                 print(Combat.wound(enemyStamina))
                 print("1. Continue")
                 print("2. Test your LUCK?")
                 choice2 = input ("Make your choice: (1, 2): ")
                 choice2 = int(choice2)
                 if choice2 == 1:
                      continue
                 elif choice2 == 2:
                      pass
                 else:
                      print("Try that again...")
                      
        elif choice == 2:
            print("Here are your items!")
        elif choice == 3:
            print("You fled... (-2 STAMINA)")
        else:
            print("Try that again...")
```

`enemyStamina` should be passed to the combat class in an external file

```
def wound (x):
        return x - 2
```

Then it should return to the beginning of the while loop until either entity stamina has been depleted.

One of my theories is the fact that it retrieves the enemy stamina from a dictionary within another external class called Creature:

```
class Creature:
    goblin = {
    "enemy_name" : "GOBLIN", 
    "skill" : 5, 
    "stamina" : 6
}
```

I have tried making a copy of the dictionary but believe I have done so incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. Also, I recommend that you learn about functions soon. These are a great tool to organize your code into smaller, logical pieces.

Comment: And I recommend that you read more about classes and object orient programming. The way you use them here doesn't take advantage of the full power that classes provide.

Comment: You never store HP after character gets hit ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is with the combination of these parts of your code:

```
Combat.wound(enemyStamina)

def wound (x):
        return x - 2
```

Here, the `wound()` function calculates a value by subtracting 2 from the value passed into the parameter `x`, but it doesn't change the value `x` nor the value of the variable whose value was passed to `x`.

I recommend doing something like this:

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(name, skill, stamina)
        self.name = name
        self.skill = skill
        self.stamina = stamina

    def wound(damage):
        self.stamina = self.stamina - damage
```

Notice how this version of `wound()` changes the value of `stamina`. Now you can create a creature with something like

```
goblin = Creature("goblin", 5, 6)
```

Then you can wound the goblin with

```
print(goblin.stamina) // 6
goblin.wound(2)
print(goblin.stamina) // 4
```

This `Creature` class can now be reused to make an orc, hobgoblin, dragon, or anything else you wish. You can even reuse this class to represent the hero, or you can make a separate class for the hero. I recommend that you read more about how functions and classes work to understand this and to be able to write code like this yourself.